# Magento 2: Translation doesn't works in JS files. Can anyone help on this please?

Tags: magento2, javascript, localisation, js-translation, issue

```
define(
    [
        "jquery",
        "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
        "mage/calendar",
        "mage/translate",
    ], function($, modal){
```

//     also use this on my code

```
$.mage.__('confirm'),
```

Comment: try remove the "js-translation.json" file located at pub/static/frontend/...your theme directory.
and cache flush.

Comment: Thanks Sameer for suggestion

Comment: You're welcome @ShivOmMishra :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrase
```

Source:
[Translation dictionaries and language packages](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html)

I hope, It will help you.

Thanks

Comment: thanks @Sameer Bhayani

Comment: Welcome @ShivOmMishra